# Put characters received from an array in alphabetical order without using sorting functions?

Tags: java, arrays, string, ascii, frequency

So, basically, I created an algorithm in java that takes characters from a string and counts its frequencies. Now, I need it to be printed in alphabetical order.

For example :
A freq: 3
d freq: 1
l freq: 5

Any suggestions? Here's what I have thus far.

```
     int[] charCounts(String userSort) {
        int[] counts = new int[256];
        char[] c = userSort.toCharArray();
        for (int i=0;i<c.length;++i) {
            counts[c[i]]++;
        }
        return counts;
}
```

Comment: usually it's helpful to mention the programming language that you're using, even add a tag!

Comment: I'm sorry!! My brain is so fried, lol, fixed it!

Comment: The tag 'frequency'. Is that related to the question which seems to be about printing chars? you question is not clear. either add some working code, or add some input example and expected output... at least I cannot guess what it is you would like to do. give it one more round.

Comment: Use an ordered tree

Comment: Looks like [Counting Sort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countingsort).

Comment: @AraniqueBrown  this community expect class assignments to be disclosed as such in the question's text if it is such. You are presenting a problem and a set of constraints that are a classic classroom assignment, and specially so when your previously-created algorithm is *also* a classic assignment, and the order makes *perfect sense* for an assignment with a follow-up continuation. --- However, the fact that you haven't disclosed that it is an assignment is causing a lot of confusion and even a bit of drama in the answers' section. So I'll ask directly: ***Is this an assignment?***

Comment: @AlmightyR Yes, it is an assignment. I apologize, I did not know that it was required of me to disclose that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to sort the characters within your supplied String and a simple way to do that without using any API sorting methods is to utilize two **for** loops. Of course you will need to break down the supplied string into a character array. Let's assume the supplied string is `"This is my string to sort"`:

```
String suppliedString = "This is my string to sort";
char[] charArray = suppliedString.toCharArray();
```

Now use two for loops to iterate through the Character Array and manipulate the elements of that Array to bring the least character values towards the beginning and the greater values progressively to the end. This type of sorting is called a [**Bubble Sort**](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Bubble.htm) and it goes something like this:

> **Note:** Yes...there are a lot of comments within the following code explaining what is going on. So much so that it's downright
>   cluttering. That's what's so good about editors, you can easily delete
>   them if you don't want them.

```
// The supplied String to sort.
String suppliedString = "this is my string to sort";
// Remove all whitespaces. We don't need them for 
// this excercise since our goal is to sort and 
// get character occurrences. If you want to also
// process whitespaces then comment the code line
// below.
suppliedString = suppliedString.replace(" ", "");

// Convert the supplied string to a character array.
char[] charArray = suppliedString.toCharArray();
// Declare a Character variable to hold the current
// Character Array element value being processed.
char tempChar;
// Iterate through the character array with two
// FOR loops so as to create a string which will
// hold the least character values to the greatest
// character values.
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
        // Is the current Array element value in 
        // charArray[i] less than the what is in
        // the current Array element for charArray[j]?
        if (charArray[i] < charArray[j]) {
            // Yes it is...
            // Hold our current character element value.
            tempChar = charArray[i];
            // Now make the Array element at index i hold
            // what is in Array element at index j.
            charArray[i] = charArray[j];
            // Make the Array element at index j hold what
            // was originally in the Array element at index i.
            charArray[j] = tempChar;
        }
        // No it's not so let's continue iterations through 
        // the character array using the index place-holder 
        // j to see if there are still more character Array 
        // element values less than what is currently in the 
        // Character Array index place-holder i location.
    }
    // continue iterations through the character array 
    // using the index place-holder i to see if there 
    // are still more character Array element values less
    // that what might be in the Character Array index place
    // -holder j location.
}

//==============================================
// For your project you don't need this little
// section. I just added it so you can see what 
// the sort looks like.
// Now use yet another FOR loop to convert the 
// the sorted Character Array (charArray[]) back
// to a sorted string.
// Declare and initialize a String variable to 
// Null String (""). This variable will hold the
// new Sorted String.
String sortedString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    sortedString+= charArray[i];
}

// Display the sorted String. If you don't
// want spaces in your sort then use: 
// System.out.println(sortedString.trim());
// Spaces have the least value (32) so they
// will almost always be at the beginning of
// the sorted string.
System.out.println("Sorted String: -->   " + sortedString + "\n");
//==============================================

// Now that the Character Array is sorted let's
// use yet another couple FOR loops to figure out
// the occurrences of each character. We'll use our 
// same String variable (sortedString) to hold our 
// display text to console. (Note: There's a lot of 
// ways to do this sort of thing in Java)
int counter; // counter used to keep track of char occurrences.
sortedString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    counter = 0; // new character. Make sure counter is zeroed
    // Iterate through the entire array and count
    // those that are the same.   
    for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) {
        if (charArray[i] == charArray[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    // Make sure we don't place duplicate character/frequencies
    // into the string we're creating.
    if (!sortedString.contains("Char: " + charArray[i])) {
        // Add the current character and occurrence
        // to our string variable.
        if (sortedString.equals("")) {
            sortedString+= "Char: " + charArray[i] + " - Freq: " + counter; 
        } 
        else {
            sortedString+= " || Char: " + charArray[i] + " - Freq: " + counter; 
        }
    }
}
// Display the sorted characters and their occurrences.
System.out.println(sortedString);
```

Yup, a lot of **for** loops in that code. Once you understand the code then delete all the commenting if you like. Once you do you'll see that there really isn't too much code to accomplish this task.

Comment: The question title says *without using sorting functions*. I'm unsure if using *BubbleSort* conflicts with it. Either OP wants to know how to write sorting on his own, which you explained well, or he wants a solution which doesn't use *sorting* at all.

Comment: @Zabuza Sorting *functions* probably refers to Java's ***builtin*** sorting functions. In fact, I strongly suspect that the whole point of the assignment is for the OP to (understand and) implement a sorting ***algorithm*** (completely different from *"frunction"*) himself; such as BubbleSort. In fact, I strongly suspect BubbleSort is ***exactly*** the algorithm the tutor would have in mind for the exercise, and anything more advanced is extra-points.

Comment: @Zabuza The OP states that he needs the array's contents to be printed in alphabetical order. Unless we talk about a *dumb* algorithm, like something that goes through the array multiple times printing the "lowest" non-printed value each time, then the array elements would have to either be rearranged in-place or rearranged to a new (sorted) array... ***That's sorting***. --- AFAICS, the requirement makes no sense unless the situation is exactly what I described: An assignment meant to teach or test the OP about an understanding of how sorting *algorithms* work.

Comment: Just like many texts (good or bad), most can be interpreted at least 10 different ways. I suppose this OP's post is no different. There are a **lot** of methods (functions or whatever you like to call them) used within the code I have presented above but for the life of me I can't figure out how one can see a call to a **BubbleSort** method. I only see the use of a **concept** within raw code but then again, that's just me and perhaps some others that actually know the difference. Never the less, @Zabuza could very well be right. It would be nice if the OP would let us know.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thank you! This is extremely helpful. I kept hearing about Bubble Sort but no one was willing to explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Store your results in an ordered map, like a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Iterating over the keys in the map will output them in sorted order with no additional processing required.

This would require a small modification to your code. Instead of returning an array, you would return a [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html):

```
 SortedMap<Character, Integer> charCounts(String userSort) {
    SortedMap<Character, Integer> counts = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i < userSort.size(); ++i) {
        char c = userSort.charAt(i);
        if(counts.contains(c)) {
             counts.put(c, counts.get(c) + 1);
        } else {
             counts.put(c, 1);
        }
    }
    return counts;
 }
```

You can now iterate the characters with something like:

```
 for(Character c : charCounts(...).keySet()) ...
```

The `Set` returned by [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet--) will be sorted like the map itself.

If you are stuck with the particular function you provided, you can add the results to the map after calling it, and then iterate over the map as before:

```
 int[] counts = charCounts(...);
 TreeMap<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
 for(char c = 0; c < counts.length; c++)
      map.put(c, counts[c]);
```

Comment: This is probably a class assignment. I don't think he's meant to solve it with an ordered collection. As indicated in the title, he's not allowed to use a (built-in) sorting *functions*. That doesn't mean a sorting *algorithm* can't be used. The purpose of the assignment is in fact probably for him to implement such a sorting algorithm himself; I can even guesstimate that the tutor has bubble sort in mind specifically. --- I'm downvoting this because it would defeat the purpose of the exercise. Following this answer would be a disservice to the OP.

Comment: @AlmightyR. Since you believe that this is not following the spirit of the question, I respectfully accept your downvote. However, since the purpose of this site is to provide help beyond OP, I will retain this technically correct answer.

Comment: I think answers of this type are very useful but obviously don't meet all of the environmental constraints of the question. So, it shouldn't be the only answer and probably not the accepted answer.

Comment: @Tom. I could not agree more

Comment: @MadPhysicist The purpose of this site is to help with the questions being asked (OP or later readers; correct), **taking into account the circumstances in which those questions are being asked**. *Answers* should provide ***answers***; not solutions. --- Simply providing a solution, specially one that cheats the wording of the question to avoid it's circumstances through a shady work-around, is definitely not a valid *answer* in IMHO. It's no different than code-only "answers": It defeats the ***purpose*** of the question instead of *resolving* it, and as such, ***helps no one***.

Comment: @AlmightyR the circumstances to which you are referring are not stated anywhere. While your assumptions are plausible, never forget that they are just assumptions. Also keep in mind that my "solution" is not devoid of explanation about  how I decided to recommend that particular course of action.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  The OP states: `"I created an algorithm in java that takes characters from a string and counts its frequencies. Now, I need it to be printed in alphabetical order."` --- Either part is a ***very*** common assignment in for beginner-level programming classes. It can be (*very*) safely assumed to be an assignment from either. But then, there is order that, and first + second ***virtually guarantees*** that this is an assignment. It's called *indirect communication*. There is something being told there without the OP explicitly saying it. --- Trying to dodge that fact is silly.

Comment: @AlmightyR. You are probably correct, but it still sounds like a series of very plausible *assumptions*. Until OP confirms or denies your *theory*, it will remain just that. I am not trying to convince you to agree with me or anything like that, just to accept that you are constructing a value judgement based on incomplete information. There is nothing wrong with that: after all, heuristics make for good algorithms (often). You ought to be able to understand why we don't see eye to eye on this. I certainly understand and respect your downvote.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Welp, [OP just confirmed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858061/put-characters-received-from-an-array-in-alphabetical-order-without-using-sortin?noredirect=1#comment80736760_46858061). ***Yes, it's an assignment***. Will you please stop pretending that *"maybe it isn't!"* now?  --- BTW, I understand and respect your answer, for what it is; what I don't *"respect"* (accept) is the fact that you know or should know that this is an assignment, for how "obviously-an-assignment" it is; yet you're pretending that you don't see it as "obviously-an-assignment". 

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement what is called `Counting Sort` ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countingsort)).

It works well if your **universe** (the set of possible characters) is small, compared to the size of the input you want to sort.

It's relatively easy. You previously know the correct order of your **universe** and setup a sorted `Map` (`LinkedHashMap` to preserve order). For our example, let's limit the universe to `[a, b, c, d, e]`.

```
LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> charToCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
charToCount.put('a', 0);
charToCount.put('b', 0);
charToCount.put('c', 0);
charToCount.put('d', 0);
charToCount.put('e', 0);
```

Now you traverse your `input` and count all occurrences:

```
String inputToSort = ...
for (char c : inputToSort.toCharArray()) {
    // Increase counter by one
    charToCount.put(c, charToCount.get(c) + 1);
}
```

Finally you simply traverse your `Map` in the previously known correct order and print each character the amount it occurred often:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Every character
for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : charToCount.entrySet()) {
    // How often it occurred
    for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
        sb.append(entry.getKey());
    }
}
String output = sb.toString();
```

Of course you can optimize the procedure a bit, but that is the general procedure. The linked Wikipedia article contains more information.

For example you can, in practice, use the `int` value of every `char` in Java to extract the correct order. By that you don't need to initialize the `Map` with the whole universe and can leave out stuff which does not even occur once. Also you can drop the `Map` in favor of an `array` which preserves order by definition and is extremely optimized by your machine. The `index` for a `char` then is based on its `int` value, as said before.

Answer (score -1):

You are 80% there. You already have a sorted map like that which [@MadPhysicist](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46859859/edit) refers to. You are using a distribute-gather technique. I guess you don't realize that in the distribution, you've already sorted the characters. You just need to gather them up again for output. Distributing and gathering can be a form of sorting. But, it's not using a sort function per se.

I'm not going to give code for this because you've got a good start and you are only asking for suggestions.

First, the distribution part that you've already done:

ASCII only has 128 characters. But, Java doesn't use ASCII anyway. Even so, it seems reasonable to limit your scope for this exercise to the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block plus the C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement block, which is what your `new int[256]` does.

So, are the characters in those blocks in the order you want and isn't that the same order as in `counts`?  You've distributed the characters into ordered boxes as counts. `counts[c[i]]++`

Gathering:

You just have to gather them up again in the desired order and write them out in the desired format. A loop over `counts` would do that. Your question title asks to put the characters in order so that implies output putting the same number of characters. You can convert the count of a character into repeated characters. If your goal is to simply print them out, you can do that in a loop; Otherwise, you'd have to [build a string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

BTW—The order is called lexicographic because it is based on a character set or encoding definition. Alphabetic implies either a chosen sequence of symbols (in the mathematical sense) or a particular writing system of a particular natural language with some letters designated by popular convention or language academy as "the alphabet". For example, the Danish alphabet in Latin script: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ. See [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: The question asks for suggestions as if it was for a final solution by the asker for study or homework. The problem was nearly solved already.

Comment: Which part is a suggestion relevant to the actual question? `Distributing and gathering can be a form of sorting. But, it's not using a sort function per se.`?